# Take an img src and set it at background of upper div - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that has an img inside it. As those are generated, I want to take the img src and set it in the background property of the outer div.

(I am trying to do a circle image, then followed a tutorial)

I have this.

The JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready = (function() {
            var someId = $("#someId");
            $.each(someId, function(index, value) {
                var src = value.find('img').attr('src');
                value.css('background', 'url(' + src + ') no-repeat');
            });
        });
</script>
```

The HTML

```
<div class="body">
    <h2><img alt="image" src="img-src" /></h2>
</div>
```

However when I run the site, the background property is not set.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AGvP3/1/) is the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Few Observations

- `value` inside the handler is not a jQuery object so it won't have methods like [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [document.ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) is a function you need to pass your ready handler as a parameter to it
- you can use the [.css(property, function(){})](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value) to set the css property

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var someId = $("#someId");
    someId.css('background', function () {
        console.log('x')
        return 'url(' + $(this).find('img').attr('src') + ') no-repeat'
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9cv73/)

Comment: Thank you worked fine, just add ' ; ' on the end of your brackets :)

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors, missing a `});` at the end of the $.each( code.

And logic errors as well. `value` in your code is going to be the imgs you found via .find(), and you're trying to to take the src of those images and set that as the background of the image...

setting a background on an image makes no sense whatsoever.